# Include logging configuration in file read by configparser

Tags: python, logging, configparser

I use configparser to read some configuration options for my application and I'd like to read the logging configuration as well.

Can I do that in the same file?
How should I name the logging specific sections?

Comment: Have you looked at `logging.config.fileConfig`?

Comment: Yes, I have. I saw that I can give it an instance of the RawConfigParser. So should I just give it the object after the execution of the read() function of the configparser?

Comment: It takes a file name, not a file object.

Comment: Apparently, it does. I just passed my configparser object as argument and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since the advice from @chepner helped.

Considering the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig), I could just pass the object the `configparser.ConfigParser` creates as argument to the `logging.config.fileConfig` function

Here is the snipper:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['general'] = {'default-option': 'blah'}
config.read(configFile)
# Logging configuration
logging.config.fileConfig(config, disable_existing_loggers=False)
```